# When and where should I replace tokens on a custom path for metatag context?

Tags: 7, tokens, meta-tags

I have custom tokens defined in `hook_token_info()` and `hook_tokens()`.  I need these tokens to populate metatag data for the **metagag** module on a custom path.  I have the **context** module installed as well.

The path routes to a callback that loads the object I need to pass to `token_replace().`

My question is when and where do I call `token_replace()` so the tokens are available to **metatag context** on page load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct place to specify the replace data was in `hook_tokens()`.  I did not follow the original tutorial correctly and thought since my tokens were not available I was in the wrong place.

I ended up specifying my tokens as the **current-page** type.  After I did that, they displayed and I can now use them for my metatags.

As a side note, I did discover you need to run cron after you make changes to `hook_token_info()`.